# can we check folder permission on remote machine using c#

Tags: c#-3.0

can we check folder permission on remote machine using c#.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the account used to execute your code has access to those folders then, yes.

You can use the **GetAccessControl** method of a **DirectoryInfo** instance.

If the folder isn't shared, you can always use the C share: \\somemachine\C$\program files